# How can I recreate svg <line> elements using d34raphael?

Tags: svg, raphael, d3.js

I know [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) can create paths, but not lines. I know [d3](http://d3js.org/) can create both.

I would like to create a box and whisker chart, similar to [this one](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/box.html), but horizontal instead of vertical. I have json data in the form:

```
{
    "lowestValue":"53",
    "lowerQuartile":"63",
    "medianValue":"73",
    "upperQuartile":"80",
    "highestValue":"99",
    "targetValue":"80"
},
...
```

How can I create a (or several) box and whisker plot(s) with [d34raphael](http://webmonarch.github.com/d34raphael/) or with pure raphael, so that it will display properly in IE7/IE8?

Here is a picture of the end goal:

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is such a similar primitive that it seems like it would be easy to recreate such a graph using raw Raphael (which seems increasingly to be my preference these days).  Consider such a utility function as this:

```
function whisker( paper, x, y, width, height, data )
{
    var x1 = x + data.lowestValue * width / 100, x2 = x + data.highestValue * width / 100;
    var outer_range = paper.path( [ "M", x1, y + height * 0.25, "L", x1, y + height * 0.75, "M", x1, y + height / 2, "L", x2, y + height / 2, "M", x2, y + height / 4, "L", x2, y + height * 0.75 ] ).attr( { fill : 'none', stroke: 'gray' } );
    var inner_range = paper.rect( x + ( width * data.lowerQuartile / 100 ), y, width * ( data.upperQuartile - data.lowerQuartile ) / 100, height, 0 ).attr( { fill: 'lightgray', stroke: 'black' } );
    var median = paper.path( [ "M", x + width * data.medianValue / 100, y, "L", x + width * data.medianValue / 100, y + height ] ).attr( { fill: 'none', stroke: 'black' } );;
    var target = paper.circle( x + ( width * data.targetValue / 100 ), y + height / 2, height / 4 ).attr( { fill: 'black' } );
}
```

The sixth parameter is simply your json data.  You would need to increment the y value for each whisker, of course.  Here's the [code in action](http://voidblossom.com/tests/whiskers.php) on my website.

Comment: I haven't had much luck with the path so far, thank you for the example code. I'll try it today, and see how it works!

Comment: Fantastic! I edited the function slightly because I like taller whiskers, but it worked flawlessly. Thank you Kevin!